# Comparing results of a previous query within a recursive query

Tags: postgresql, case, recursive-query

I have set up a query to find the earliest time Person X was promoted to a specific rank-

```
"firsttimeEMplus" AS (
    SELECT MIN(ra."EffectiveDate")
    FROM rankachievement ra
    WHERE ra."NewRank" IN ('Executive Manager', 
         'Associate Director', 
         'Director', 
         'Senior Director', 
         'Executive Director', 
         'Managing Director'))
```

Now what I would like to do is to use the result of this query as part of a CASE statement within my recursive query where I figure out if Person X was promoted before their parent. So, where the child firsttimeEMplus < parent firsttimeEMplus

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (**child**"firsttimeEMplus" <= **parent**"firsttimeEMplus) THEN etc....
```

But I am confused on what syntax would allow me to compare the parent to the child like this, or if I can even do something like this within a CASE statement. If anyone could provide guidance or resources or where I could find examples of how this might work, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Only immediate parent, or any parent?  If you restrict to immediate parent, then you do not need recursion.

Comment: @MikeOrganek only immediate parent

Comment: If it is immediate parent only, then you need join your hierarchy table to itself only once, and put a `boolean` or whatever column in there to signify that a child made `EMplus` before his parent.  That becomes a characteristic of each person record.  If you need to recurse for some other reason, you can mark the record during the recursion.

Comment: @MikeOrganek This might be a dumb question, but what I'm confused about is what syntax to use to determine if the child made EM plus before the parent. I may be totally overthinking this. Just trying to figure out how to format the syntax so I can put the comparison in a CASE statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is without recursion.

The idea is to get a list of all your persons with their `first_time_em` date.  Using a `left join` and a `filter` clause will return all persons whether they ever made it to EM level.

Join this result back onto itself, connecting each record with its parent record.  Again this is a `left join` since the person at the top of the hierarchy should not have a parent.

The `case` statement could be just a `boolean` comparison with `coalesce` since all we need is `true`/`false`.  The possible conditions are:

1. Child's `first_time_em` is before parent's `first_time_em`, which yields `true`
2. Child has a `first_time_em` and the boss does not (`null`), which `coalesce()` turns into `9999-12-31`, which yields `true`
3. Child has no `first_time_em` (`null`), yields `false` by the `else`
4. Child's `first_time_em` is after parent's `first_time_em`, yields `false` by the 'else`
5. Neither child nor parent have a `first_time_em`, yields `false` by the `else`

```
with person_achievement as (
  select p.person_id, p.parent_id, 
         MIN(ra."EffectiveDate") 
           filter (when ra."NewRank" in 
             ('Executive Manager', 'Associate Director', 'Director', 
              'Senior Director', 'Executive Director', 'Managing Director')
           ) as first_time_em
    from person p
    left join rankachievement ra 
      on ra.person_id = p.person_id
)
select pc.*, 
       case
         when pc.first_time_em < coalesce(pp.first_time_em, '9999-12-31') then true
         else false
       end as made_em_before_boss
  from person_achievement pc
  left join person_achievement pp
    on pp.person_id = pc.parent_id
;
```